# Notepad++ Search for text between tags more then 20 characters

Tags: notepad++, search

To find tags and replace text between tags in Notepad++, I do use the following example:

```
(?<=<barcode>)(.*)(?=</barcode>)
```

I was wondering if it is possible to search between certain tags for a text that contains more than 20 characters?

Comment: Why does this code works only up to 20 characters?

Comment: Maybe figure out where to slap in `{21,}` somewhere.

Comment: Could it be some spaces or linebreaks within the string?

Comment: Just replace `.*` with `.{21,}` or `.{20,}` depending if you want strictly `>20` or `>=20`  characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use or adapt the following expression for your needs.

`[\S]` finds all characters except space (identical to [^\s]) and `{21,}` requires at least 21 characters of text.

```
(?<=<barcode>)([\S]{21,})(?=</barcode>)
```

For text with spaces use:

```
(?<=<barcode>)(.{21,})(?=</barcode>)
```

[image]

Comment: I knew there was a way to do that!

Comment: Great! That works... Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, I could not find the grey/green ✓
Now I did :-)